# pandas timestamps comparison doesn`t work properly

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe indexed by timestamps:

```
                                  A
t                                  
2020-07-27 11:00:28.575000+01:00  0
2020-07-27 11:00:43.775000+01:00  1
2020-07-27 11:00:44.175000+01:00  2
2020-07-27 11:00:44.475000+01:00  3
2020-07-27 11:00:45.575000+01:00  4
```

I want to find all the rows that are greater than a variable:

```
start_time
Out[31]: datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27, 11, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' LMT-1 day, 23:59:00 STD>)
```

But it returns noting.

If I take the first index:

```
df.index[0]
Out[32]: Timestamp('2020-07-27 11:00:28.575000+0100', tz='Europe/London')
```

and compare it with `start_time`:

```
df.index[0] > start_time
Out[34]: False
```

and also if I convert the start_time to `timestamp`:

```
pd.Timestamp(start_time)
Out[36]: Timestamp('2020-07-27 11:00:00-0001', tz='Europe/London')

df.index[0] > pd.Timestamp(start_time)
Out[37]: False
```

Why doesn`t it work properly?

Comment: why don't you construct in "native pandas", i.e. `start_time = pd.Timestamp('2020-07-27 11:00:00', tz='Europe/London')`? By the way, judging form your output, I think `start_time` isn't localized correctly; the `repr` should be `datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27, 11, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' BST+1:00:00 DST>)`.

Comment: You right. It was defined by other developer as: start_time = datetime.datetime(...).replace(timezone('Europe/London')).... Which cause the whole problem...

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and it seems like the following works for me:

```
start_time = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27, 11, 0,)
df.index[0] > pd.Timestamp(start_time, tz="Europe/London")
>>> True
```

Comment: Yep, but it is not my example... :) I guess there is an issue with the timezones...

Comment: yup, where does your `start_time` come from? how is it constructed?